# Apache Camel set file extension

Tags: apache-camel

I'm getting xml listings from HTTP POST body and then try to save it as XML document on filesystem. Unfortunately, Camel do not automatically provide file extension, and file is saved without it, so I cannot open it in my XML-viewer. Also, I want to preserve auto-generated file names (like **ID-my_PC_name-some_strange_numbers**) to avoid file overriding or data loss. After reading articles about Camel Simple language still no luck. Any help appreciated. This is my configuration:

```
.from("jetty:http://localhost:4422/input")
      .to("direct:fileCopy");

 .from("direct:fileCopy")
       //here I want to set file extension to .xml
       .to("file:D:/inprogress")
       .log("Incoming file saved to Inprogress directory");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option `filename` to set the pattern of the file that you want to generate.

```
.from("direct:fileCopy")
       .to("file:D:/inprogress?filename=mydata-${date:now:yyyyMMdd}.xml
")
```

will generate a file `mydata-20150303.xml`

if you want to use the message id , which is the unique id on exchange you can

```
.from("direct:fileCopy")
           .to("file:D:/inprogress?filename=mydata-${id}.xml
    ")
```

will generate a file `mydata-SOME_RANDOM_ALPHANUMERIC_ID.xml`

[Apache Camel File Copy](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution do not prevent files from overriding each other, because file names are not unique.

Comment: But you can use a pattern which is unique for example include upto milliseconds in the pattern , and you should be good to go , isnt it ?

Comment: I hope you understand that this approach is unreliable--what if i have 2 messages at same time? One of them will be lost..

Comment: The filename options supports many ways, so if you want an extension to the id generated, then set filename=${id}.txt - where .txt is the file extension in this example. The filename is based on the simple language: http://camel.apache.org/simple

Comment: You can use id variable in the name to use the message id, which will be unique . something like .to("file:D:/inprogress?filename=mydata-${id}.xml . @ClausIbsen just saw you also mentioned the same approach. thanks

Comment: @ClausIbsen, thanks a lot! Now it works! Could you copy your comment as answer so i can accept it?